# MySQL 5.6.20 error in alter ignore table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I add this line for add `ignore` to MySql database :

```
ALTER IGNORE cms_books_author name ADD UNIQUE(name)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error
SQL query:


ALTER IGNORE cms_books_author name ADD UNIQUE(name)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'efcms_books_author name ADD UNIQUE(name)' at line 1
```

Mysql version is : `5.6.20`

how do I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: missing the table and adjust the syntax of the unique index : `ALTER IGNORE table cms_books_author ADD UNIQUE(name);`

Comment: @amdixon:  you right. add answer for accept for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**syntax issues**

> 1. alter ignore missing the table keyword
> 2. syntax should only include the name within the unique index not after the tablename

**adjusted**

```
ALTER IGNORE table cms_books_author ADD UNIQUE(name);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f9c29)

---

[**alter table syntax**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

> ```
> ALTER [ONLINE | OFFLINE] [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name
>     [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
>     [partition_options]
>
> ...
>
> alter_specification:
>     table_options
>   | ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
>         UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY] [index_name]
>         [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
> ```